# OctopusDeploy: Is it possible to specify a folder where a Windows service should be deployed?

Tags: windows-services, octopus-deploy

When you deploy a Windows service with Octopus Deploy, you can specifiy the package identifier to be used. As far as I understood this, the package identifier will be used as the folder the Windows service is running in.

E.g. a service called `MyService` with version number `1.8.7` and environment `Production` would be stored under `C:\Octopus\Applications\Production\MyService\1.8.7`.

My question now is if one can specifiy a folder to deploy to. The reason behind this is that there are different instances of `MyService` for different customers and they both should run on the same machine in our setup.

If the same package (and package identifier) is used for multiple services, can we somehow specifiy a folder to deploy to?

**EDIT:**
I found out that a second service with the same specification (but other configuration) will generate a folder called `C:\Octopus\Applications\Production\MyService\1.8.7_1`. In my opinion, it still would be better if the user could influence this behaviour and specify a folder name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set a custom installation directory by clicking on "Configure Features" on your deployment step and checking "Custom Installation Directory".

You can also use variables in the Custom Installation Directory.

[image: Configure Features]

[image: Custom Installation Directory]

Comment: Thanks Ryan. Of course, this is hidden in the `features` section. I should have know it.

Comment: In fact, what I really was searching for was the `tenanted deployment`. So just if anyone searches the same thing, follow https://octopus.com/docs/deployment-patterns/multi-tenant-deployments.

Comment: Ah, good call. I thought you might have been using tenants already but wanted to customize the install directory.